# Ckeditor ruby gem adds ">" at the end of the entries every time a user edits the textarea entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ckeditor

Ckeditor ruby gem is adding a ">" at the end of my content entries every time a user edits the content. 
Here is a video of it happening: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16sus8LGxHBZLFs_ts5_SJJSwLfisJzom/view?usp=sharing

Here is my update_row controller code for the text_component model. The textarea input is being saved in the content column.
  def update_row
    @text_component = TextComponent.find(params.fetch("id_to_modify"))

```
@text_component.tab_id = params.fetch("tab_id")
@text_component.content = params.fetch("content")

if @text_component.valid?
  @text_component.save

  redirect_to("/guides/"+params.fetch("guide_id"), :notice => "Text component updated successfully.")
else
  @guide = Guide.find(params.fetch("guide_id"))
  render("guide_templates/show.html.erb")
end
end
```

ANSWERED: here is the working form code in my edit_form view:

```
  <form action="/update_text_component/<%= @text_component.id %>"  method="post">
  <!--input for guide_id -->
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="hidden" id="guide_id" name="guide_id" class="form-control" value="<%= params.fetch("guide_id") %>">
  </div>
    <!-- input for tab_id -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="tab_id" name="tab_id" class="form-control" value="<%= params.fetch("tab_id") %>">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">
      Content
    </label>

    <textarea id="content" name="content" class="ckeditor" rows="10"><%= raw @text_component.content %></textarea>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary">
    Update text component
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: See update on the questions which shows my the edit form on the text_component view. The ">" is being added at the end of the content. I should also note that paragraphs "<p>&nbsp;</p>" are also being added in between some paragraphs. It's hard to tell why it adds it to some and not to others.

Comment: It looks like I figured it out... It does not add the ">" or the paragraphs if I just write the existing value in between the <textarea></textarea>  tags instead of the value= option. Updated my view in case anyone else runs into this issue. newby mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <form action="/update_text_component/<%= @text_component.id %>"  method="post">
  <!--input for guide_id -->
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="hidden" id="guide_id" name="guide_id" class="form-control" value="<%= params.fetch("guide_id") %>">
  </div>
    <!-- input for tab_id -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="tab_id" name="tab_id" class="form-control" value="<%= params.fetch("tab_id") %>">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">
      Content
    </label>

    <textarea id="content" name="content" class="ckeditor" rows="10"><%= raw @text_component.content %></textarea>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary">
    Update text component
  </button>
</form>
```